# C++ compiler does not apply template

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors, c++14

I try my first steps towards templates. I have a class that reads configuration parameters using boost/property_tree. Currently I have a dozens of getters that do all the same. For example:

```
inline std::string getSocket(void) {
    return any_cast<std::string>(param["socket"]);
}
```

Now I tried to create a template:

Declaration:

```
template <typename T, typename R>
R getValue(const std::string &);
```

Definition:

```
template <typename T=std::string, typename R=std::string>
R MilterCfg::getValue(const std::string &key) {
    if (param.count(key) == 0)
        return "";
    return any_cast<T>(param[key]);
}
```

Call in another cpp-file:

```
mfsocket = ::config->getValue<>("socket");
```

The compiler does not accept this:

```
/Users/croessner/ClionProjects/sigh/src/milter.cpp:491:30: error: no matching member function for call to 'getValue'
    mfsocket = ::config->getValue<>("socket");
               ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~
/Users/croessner/ClionProjects/sigh/src/config.h:112:11: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument 'T'
    R getValue(const std::string &);
      ^
```

I try this on Mac OS X El-Capitan with the clang++ compiler. I think I really miss some understanding of templates. But what am I missing here?

Here is the complete header:

```
#ifndef SRC_CONFIG_H_
#define SRC_CONFIG_H_

#include <map>
#include <string>

#include <boost/any.hpp>
#include <boost/program_options/variables_map.hpp>

namespace po = boost::program_options;

extern bool debug;

namespace conf {
    using boost::any_cast;

    typedef std::map<std::string, boost::any> config_t;

    /*!
     * \brief Read a configuration file and store settings
     *
     * All milter settings may be stored in a configuration file. This class
     * reads a default configuration file, if not given as command line
     * argument and extracts all keys and values. For each key that is not
     * found, but requested my the milter, a default value is defined in a
     * local data structure.
     */
    class MilterCfg {
    public:
        MilterCfg(const po::variables_map &);

        virtual ~MilterCfg() = default;

        /*!
         * \brief The milter socket
         *
         * The socket may have one of three formats. First is
         * inet:portnumber\@host, second is inet6:portnumber\@host6 or a unix
         * socket like unix:/pat/to/socket. host and host6 may be a hostname
         * or a valid IP address. IPv6 addresses must be written in squared
         * braces.
         */
        inline std::string getSocket(void) {
            return any_cast<std::string>(param["socket"]);
        }

        /*!
         * The milter will drop its privileges to this user
         */
        inline std::string getUser(void) {
            return any_cast<std::string>(param["user"]);
        }

        /*!
         * The milter will drop its privileges to this group
         */
        inline std::string getGroup(void) {
            return any_cast<std::string>(param["group"]);
        }

        /*!
         * \brief An optional PID file
         *
         * If desired, a PID file may be created on startup. It will be
         * automatically removed, when the milter gets stopped again.
         */
        inline std::string getPidFile(void) {
            return any_cast<std::string>(param["pidfile"]);
        }

        /*!
         * \brief Map file containing S/MIME certificates
         *
         * This file contains a mapping between email addresses and
         * associated S/MIME certificates and keys.
         */
        inline std::string getMapFile(void) {
            return any_cast<std::string>(param["mapfile"]);
        }

        /*!
         * \brief Path to a temporary directory
         *
         */
        inline std::string getTmpDir(void) {
            return any_cast<std::string>(param["tmpdir"]);
        }

#if !__APPLE__ && !defined _NOT_DAEMONIZE
        /*!
         * \brief Bring the milter to background
         *
         * The milter gets a daemon. The root path is set to '/' and the
         * standard in and out channels are closed
         */
        inline bool getDaemon(void) {
            return any_cast<bool>(param["daemon"]);
        }
#endif  // !__APPLE__ && !defined _NOT_DAEMONIZE

        template <typename T, typename R>
        R getValue(const std::string &);

    private:
        /*!
         * \brief Data store for configuration settings
         */
        config_t param;

        /*!
         * \brief Default settings for the milter
         *
         * If a required setting could not be read from the configuration, a
         * default setting will be used from this data structure.
         */
        struct {
            //! \brief Milter socket
            std::string socket  = "inet:4000@127.0.0.1";
            //! \brief Milter system user
            std::string user    = "milter";
            //! \brief Milter system group
            std::string group   = "milter";
            //! \brief Optional PID file
            std::string pidfile = std::string();
#if !__APPLE__ && !defined _NOT_DAEMONIZE
            //! \brief Run the milter as a daemon process
            bool daemon         = false;
#endif  // !__APPLE__ && !defined _NOT_DAEMONIZE
            //! \brief Location for the map file
            std::string mapfile = std::string();
            //! \brief Location for temporary files
            std::string tmpdir = "/tmp";
        } defaults;
    };
}  // namespace conf

#endif  // SRC_CONFIG_H_
```

And the cpp file:

```
#include "config.h"

#include <iostream>

#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/ini_parser.hpp>

namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

namespace conf {
    using boost::any_cast;

    MilterCfg::MilterCfg(const po::variables_map &vm) {
        std::string conffile = vm["config"].as<std::string>();

        boost::property_tree::ptree pt;
        try {
            if (fs::exists(fs::path(conffile))
                && fs::is_regular(fs::path(conffile))) {
                boost::property_tree::ini_parser::read_ini(conffile, pt);
            } else {
                std::cerr << "Error: Unable to read config file "
                          << conffile << std::endl;
            }
        }
        catch (const std::exception &e) {
            std::cerr << "Error: " << e.what() << std::endl;
        }

        try {
            param["socket"] = pt.get<std::string>("Milter.socket");
        }
        catch (...) {
            param["socket"] = defaults.socket;
        }

        try {
            param["user"] = pt.get<std::string>("Milter.user");
        }
        catch (...) {
            param["user"] = defaults.user;
        }

        try {
            param["group"] = pt.get<std::string>("Milter.group");
        }
        catch (...) {
            param["group"] = defaults.group;
        }

        try {
            param["pidfile"] = pt.get<std::string>("Milter.pidfile");
        }
        catch (...) {
            param["pidfile"] = defaults.pidfile;
        }

        try {
            param["mapfile"] = pt.get<std::string>("Milter.mapfile");
        }
        catch (...) {
            param["mapfile"] = defaults.mapfile;
        }

        try {
            param["tmpdir"] = pt.get<std::string>("Milter.tmpdir");
        }
        catch (...) {
            param["tmpdir"] = defaults.tmpdir;
        }

#if !__APPLE__ && !defined _NOT_DAEMONIZE
        try {
            param["daemon"] = pt.get<bool>("Milter.daemon");
        }
        catch (...) {
            param["daemon"] = defaults.daemon;
        }
#endif  // !__APPLE__ && !defined _NOT_DAEMONIZE

        if (::debug) {
            std::cout << "Configuration file values:" << std::endl;

            std::cout << "user="
                << any_cast<std::string>(param["user"])
                << std::endl;
            std::cout << "group="
                << any_cast<std::string>(param["group"])
                << std::endl;
            std::cout << "socket="
                << any_cast<std::string>(param["socket"])
                << std::endl;
            std::cout << "pidfile="
                << any_cast<std::string>(param["pidfile"])
                << std::endl;
#if !__APPLE__ && !defined _NOT_DAEMONIZE
            std::cout << "daemon="
                << std::boolalpha << any_cast<bool>(param["daemon"])
                << std::endl;
#endif  // !__APPLE__ && !defined _NOT_DAEMONIZE
            std::cout << "mapfile="
                << any_cast<std::string>(param["mapfile"])
                << std::endl;
            std::cout << "tmpdir="
                << any_cast<std::string>(param["tmpdir"])
                << std::endl;
        }
    }

    template <typename T=std::string, typename R=std::string>
    R MilterCfg::getValue(const std::string &key) {
        if (param.count(key) == 0)
            return "";
        return any_cast<T>(param[key]);
    }

}  // namespace conf
```

So you see, a lot of repeating logic. My feeling is that this could be done more generic. Can you please give me a hint? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Default arguments go on the declaration, not the definition:

```
// declaration
template <typename T=std::string, typename R=std::string>
R getValue(const std::string &);

// definition
template <typename T, typename R>
R MilterCfg::getValue(const std::string &key) {
    if (param.count(key) == 0)
        return "";
    return any_cast<T>(param[key]);
}
```

N.b. the angle brackets at the call site are allowed but superfluous; the following is more idiomatic:

```
mfsocket = ::config->getValue("socket");
```

Comment: Ok, I changed this, but this gives new erros:
`Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > conf::MilterCfg::getValue<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > >(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
      _main in milter.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64`

Comment: @ChristianRößner Nice! Your problem is solved :) I suggest you mark this as the accepted answer, and [ask a _new_ question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) for your new problem :)

Comment: @ChristianRößner : [Template definitions go in header files, not source files](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#templates-defn-vs-decl).